# How to get notified if a state of a Virtual Machine is changed in scvmm

Tags: c#, powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Is there any way I can get callback from **scvmm** server when a state of vm is changed, e.g. if vm is stopped/suspended (using PS or c#).
So that I can avoid polling of getting the state of the VM again and again.
Do I need to use any library or is there any powershell command in scvmm?

Please help.

Comment: One idea is to create a scheduled task to check a file. And have the scvmm server put that file there during a state you care about. But I don't know if scvmm can do that. From what I just read, you could have powershell check scvmm reports/dashboard every few minutes and if what you want changed, have it report to you. Invoke-webrequest could do this with some fancy code.

Comment: Maybe another option is have the VM send info (time stamp) to a file every x mins. If the files time stamp is older than x minutes you could get alerted. All my options require a dedicated machine to do these checks.

Comment: Thanks Robbert. Checking scvmm reports/dashboard every minute will again be a polling mechanism that I want to avoid. My expectation is if I can subscribe to any service in the scvmm and sit. If the state of my VM is changed I should get a callback/notification so that i can pull the details of the VM.

Comment: You can set the switch (if Cisco) to poll an IP every x minutes. And email you. All this can be done via eem. Or the exsi can have a small host dedicated to pinging everything. And then have it email you on failure. Or have a standalone with a display be a ping server. And if something isn't working it turns red. Just a thought. I don't have an answer. Just ideas for monitoring.